# Want ti track value from user input on certain pages

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm working on a web application that involves a waste generation impact form and  waste tracking pages. I want to implement a feature where the user is asked to specify a reporting period before entering any data in the waste generation impact form. Additionally, I need to track these reporting periods and retain them when the user navigates between the waste generation impact form and waste tracking pages. If the user goes to any other page except these specific ones, I want to delete the tracked reporting period. How can I achieve this functionality, and what php or laravel methods or techniques should I use to implement it?

I had tried to store value from user input in session and a middleware to destroy session on all routes except given by name but session is destroying on storing waste generation impact data.

storing session from user input

```
 public function setReportingPeriod(Request $request){
    $reportPeriod=EsgReport::find($request->reporting_period);
    session(['reportingPeriodId' => $request->input('reporting_period')]);
    session(['reportingPeriodName' => $reportPeriod->title]);
    Session::put(['reportingPeriodId',$request->input('reporting_period')]);
    Session::put(['reportingPeriodName',$reportPeriod->title]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Reporting Period has been set.');
}
```

I am attempting to destroy the sessions within a middleware when a user is not on the index page and is accessing the "store" method for waste generation impact. However, I am encountering an issue where this approach is not effective for the "store" method.

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
$currentRouteName = $request->route()->getName();


if ($currentRouteName !== 'wasteGenerationImpact.store' && $currentRouteName !== 'wasteGenerationImpact.index')
{
    // Destroy the session when the condition is met
    Session::forget(['reportingPeriodId', 'reportingPeriodName']);
}

return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Session is a good solution for this. Perhaps you implemented something wrong. To get assistance, provide a [mre] of your specific issue. We cannot guess it from a description alone. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks